# Strip out <br /><br /> tags and replace with </p><p> tags

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database

My colleague did some back end development for me in asp.net and i did the CMS Input Pages with a Text Area. The problem is they are outputting the Paragraphs with `<br /><br />` tags when the page is generated. The spaces are big and I would prefer `<p></p>` so I can control the spacing etc. I only want the `<br />` tags in the ID `#FeaturedProjectNewsWrapper` to be changed and replaced.

I did google for an hour or so and only found this Javascript method and I tried changing the `<br>` to `<br />` but it didn't work, and it didn't work with  when I put one on a page  ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/<br>\*/g,"</p><p>"));});
</script>
```

I also found some PHP stuff but that's not any use. I am not sure how to really use ASP, so a little Javascript Solution would be good.

Here is my code ...

```
<div id="FeaturedProjectNewsWrapper">

<p class="DateStyle">20/05/2011</p>
<h2 class="ProjectNews">Employee of the Month</h2>

<p>LTM operate an Employee of the month scheme.  This was set up in 2009 to recognise and reward the hard work and dedication of individual employees across all LTM divisions.  Each month nominations are forwarded to Steven Laing who makes the final decision.  The employee is then notified and awarded £100 cash reward for their commitment and contribution to LTM’s ongoing success.<br /><br />The Employee of the Month recognition is not a substitute for our annual Employee of the Year award, the day-to-day positive recognition or reasonable pay and benefits the company has to offer.  It is really just another way of giving a special thank you to our top employee’s for their outstanding contribution in that month.<br /><br />Employee of the Month - April 2011: Zac Manning<br /><br />Congratulations go to Zac for receiving his Postgraduate Diploma in Surveying with distinction from the College of Estate Management, and also for his efforts at achieving the cHeRries Awards nominee stage for LTM Training Academy!</p>

<br style="clear:both;" />

</div>
```

Here is the URL if it's any help ...

http://www.traditionalmasonry.co.uk/News/CompanyNewsArticle.aspx

Many thanks in advanced, I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: Sorry just realised the text editor has read my tags lol! well it was my first post! This should have read as ...

Comment: My colleague did some back end development for me in asp.net and i did the CMS Input Pages with a Text Area. The problem is they are outputting the Paragraphs with <br /><br /> tags when the page is generated. The spaces are big and I would prefer </p><p> tags so I can control the spacing etc. I only want the <br /><br /> tags in the ID #FeaturedProjectNewsWrapper to be changed and replaced.

I did google for an hour or so and only found this Javascript method and I tried changing the <br> to <br /> but it didn't work, and it didn't work with <b> when I put one on a page ...

Comment: @Ellis Whitaker Consider updating the question with additional information instead of using a comment.

Comment: @Ellis: note that `<br />` contains `/`, which marks the end of a regex. Did you escape it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ellis! Just so you know, you can use some HTML tags in your posts such as `<br />`. Other invalid tags will be automatically stripped from your post. If you want to show your HTML without it being stripped or added as part of your post, you have to put ticks (the symbol above the tilde (~) on a QWERTY keyboard, to the left of the 1 key usually) around it. I have edited this into your post so you can click edit to see how I changed it. Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). For more info. :)

Comment: @Drackir: on my keyboard, the backtick (`\``) is *below* the tilde, but I think he will get it. ;-)

Comment: @Marcel: Touché. I looked and apparently still got it wrong. The key was correct anyhow. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please, don’t do that on client side with javascript if you respect the work of other people that will came after you. I know asp can look awful but it’s better to clean the code there. Make a global search through the project and find the page that has item with id "FeaturedProjectNewsWrapper". asp page usually resembles spaghetti but at least the code that inserts breaks instead of paragraphs will be on the same file with a high probability.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that with `<br/>` tags, paragraphs are de-marked from in between, whereas `<p>` tags surround the paragraphs.  Consider the following equivalents:

```
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>

first<br/>
second<br/>
third<br/>
```

If you replace `<br/>` with `</p><p>` then you'll omit the beginning `<p>` and the trailing `</p>`.  In order to do this conversion you have to be able to insert the start `<p>` and end `</p>` tags, otherwise it won't work properly.  Alternatively you might be able to control the `<br/>` spacing with CSS.

HTH.

Comment: The ending `</p>` tags are optional as [defined by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). **Paragraphs: the P element** *Start tag: required, End tag: optional*

Answer (score 0):

try with this regex: `/<br[^>]*>([^<]+)(<br>)/,"<p>$1</p>"`